# jqte: binding event to associated input element

Tags: jquery, events, jqte

I'm wrapping [jqte](http://jqueryte.com/) inside an object,

```
com.comapany.app.domElement.RtfEditor = function(inputElementId) {

    // I've also tried .bind('click', function() {}
    $('#'+inputElementId).bind('click', null, function() {
        alert('binding under construction');
    });
    
    $('#'+inputElementId).jqte();
};
```

I'm creating an instance of this in another JS file like this

```
jqEditor = new com.comapany.app.domElement.RtfEditor('testEditor');
```

**Problems, I'm facing:** 
I am able to either create a jquery text editor using `jqte` or `bind` click (or any) event, but not both at the same time. Please help!

Comment: Have you tried to bind your click event *after* initialising jqte, as it probably steals the click itself. The alternative would be using the deferred version of `on`, applied to document, to register your click event. If you can post a JSFiddle, happy to try create a working example.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie, yes I've tried that too sir. I also tried to expose a prototype method but also doesn't work. I've also inspected that jqte doesn't bind click event.

Comment: How about that JSFiddle? Save on guess-work.

Comment: I'm using JSFiddle first time, so please manage with this http://jsfiddle.net/5uLsn/1/

Comment: Ah, you need to add any external JavaScript includes to JSFiddle (e.g. the JavaScript file for rtfEditor). You add them under `external resources`, but the files must be somewhere you can access them publicly on the web (so that JSFiddle can see them).